# How to use .ai and eps file to extract object from it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, eps

I have few ai and eps file which i am able to open it in my adobe photoshop  CS3 , the file which i am having contains few info graphs but i want to extract the object from that file and what to change its color.

but i guess in .i and eps file we can't not see layers and all so can anyone please tell me how to use those files to extract object from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read an .ai or .eps file into Photoshop it rasterizes it, which means it turns everything in one into pixels (although it may preserve layer information). Thus, most of the information about individual objects is generally going to be lost.

To edit a single converted object in Photoshop, you'll need to use the tools that Photoshop offers for dealing with raster images (which are considerable).

To edit the individual objects in these files *as objects*, one needs to use a vector (as opposed to a raster) graphics editor -- like Adobe Illustrator or something similar.

Hope this helps clarify the situation for you.